# Can I run a batch jobs on another dedicated thread pool?

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-7, jsr352

Is it possible to run a batch job (JSR-352 Batch Processing) on another dedicated thread?

In my application I have several tasks that I would like to execute on another dedicated thread pool. Besides, I have tasks to execute on the default half of threads (default thread pool configured in Wildfly standalone.xml file).

Unfortunately, as far I could only set a new pool of threads for the entire mechanism:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0">
        <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
        <default-thread-pool name="batch | special"/>
        <job-repository name="in-memory">
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool name="batch">
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
        <thread-pool name="special"> //new pool
            <max-threads count="5"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
```

So in my case I can be used interchangeably **batch** or **special** thread-pool but not together for diffrent jobs.

In summary, I would like to set **thread-pool per job**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can specify batch thread-pool per job.  However, you can specify a custom thread-pool per deployment by using jboss-all.xml inside the application archive.  See [WildFly Batch Subsystem Configuration Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Batch+(JSR-352)+Subsystem+Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to define thread-pools per job. But you can define, which batch default thread pool your application will use.

1. Define an additional thread pool:

   `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0"> 
   ...
     <thread-pool name="testpool">
        <max-threads count="10"/>
        <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
     </thread-pool>
   </subsystem>`
2. Create webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-all.xml with

   `<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
      <batch xmlns="urn:jboss:batch-jberet:1.0">
         <thread-pool name="testpool"/>
      </batch>
   </jboss>`